# Ruby on Rails: test 10.21 on tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing

`Test 10.22` is supposed to be `green` but it is `red`. I added `create` method in `users_controller` and deleted another create method that was here. Is it possible create error or maybe another reasons for error?

How to fix this?

thanks

errors and files related as below:

```
ERROR["test_invalid_signup_information", UsersSignupTest, 2016-03-23 16:43:47 +0000]
 test_invalid_signup_information#UsersSignupTest (1458751427.59s)
AbstractController::ActionNotFound:         AbstractController::ActionNotFound: The action 'create' could not be found for UsersController
            test/integration/users_signup_test.rb:8:in `block (2 levels) in <class:UsersSignupTest>'
            test/integration/users_signup_test.rb:7:in `block in <class:UsersSignupTest>'
        test/integration/users_signup_test.rb:8:in `block (2 levels) in <class:UsersSignupTest>'
        test/integration/users_signup_test.rb:7:in `block in <class:UsersSignupTest>'

ERROR["test_valid_signup_information", UsersSignupTest, 2016-03-23 16:43:47 +0000]
 test_valid_signup_information#UsersSignupTest (1458751427.61s)
AbstractController::ActionNotFound:         AbstractController::ActionNotFound: The action 'create' could not be found for UsersController
            test/integration/users_signup_test.rb:21:in `block (2 levels) in <class:UsersSignupTest>'
            test/integration/users_signup_test.rb:20:in `block in <class:UsersSignupTest>'
        test/integration/users_signup_test.rb:21:in `block (2 levels) in <class:UsersSignupTest>'
        test/integration/users_signup_test.rb:20:in `block in <class:UsersSignupTest>'
  38/38: [=====================================================] 100% Time: 00:00:05, Time: 00:00:05

Finished in 5.52461s
38 tests, 153 assertions, 0 failures, 2 errors, 0 skips
```

and my codes

```
# test/integration/users_signup_test.rb
require 'test_helper'
class UsersSignupTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  test "invalid signup information" do
    get signup_path
    assert_no_difference 'User.count' do
      post users_path, user: {name: "",
                              email: "user@invalid",
                              password: "foo",
                              password_confirmation: "bar"}
    end

    assert_template 'users/new'
    assert_select 'div#error_explanation'
    assert_select 'div.field_with_errors'
  end

  test "valid signup information" do
    get signup_path
    assert_difference 'User.count', 1 do
      post_via_redirect users_path, user: {name: "Example User",
                                           email: "user@example.com",
                                           password: "password",
                                           password_confirmation: "password"}
    end
    # assert_template 'users/show'
    # assert is_logged_in?
  end
end
```

and

```
# app/controllers/users_corntroller.rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:index, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :correct_user, only: [:edit, :update]
  before_action :admin_user, only: :destroy

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def edit

  end

  def update
    if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end


  def index
    @users = User.paginate(page: params[:page])
  end

  def destroy
    User.find(params[:id]).destroy
    flash[:success] = "User deleted"
    redirect_to users_url
  end

  private
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password,
                                 :password_confirmation)
  end


  # Before filters

  # Confirms a logged-in user.
  def logged_in_user
    unless logged_in?
      store_location
      flash[:danger] = "Please log in."
      redirect_to login_url
    end
  end

  # Confirms the correct user.
  def correct_user
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    redirect_to(root_url) unless @user == current_user
  end

  # Confirms an admin user.
  def admin_user

    redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user.admin?
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      UserMailer.account_activation(@user).deliver_now
      flash[:info] = "Please check your email to activate your account."
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: where is the `create` action of he controller and the route to it, please provide them also?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have the create method in the private part of your controller. Move the create method to the public section of the controller. I'm not positive that is the problem but I am not on a development computer to see myself. Btw is this the Mike Hartl tutorial?

Comment: It is working. Yes it is his tutorial. Another question: where 10.23account activation email) is located? thanks.

Comment: @Tatyana You are welcome...Please except my answer as the solution. You can read it in the terminal/command prompt if you scroll up a little, that's were I read it, or I believe you can see it in the development.log file in the log directory, but I don't think you can open it while the server is running

Comment: Basically, I've finished  10 but for some reasons after I've deploy using heroku and click "forogot password" , i have empty page. On local machine it said that password send with instruction... so I've never got email. Should i? Also I think something wrong with migration to heroku because I've got some error messages following instruction. Anyway, I could continue to ask the question until you answer or/and I could create the new topic (there are plenty of question yet(: thanks.

Comment: @Tatyana  What is the error message? The book does mention that problems tend to happen in production that don't appear during development, thus the reason for deploying early. Did you check your email? Is it a gmail account? You may need to configure it to add less secure apps if you haven't already done so

Comment: yes, I've checked - nothing:(   I used yahoo.com and I used Mac. and mac has pretty secure setting. How to config to add "less secure app" as you said? Not really want to jeopardize the secure but want to get mail:) thanks.

Comment: @Tatyana  Create a gmail account just for this purpose, then google "gmail less secure apps", the first link is very short and helpful. Also, what were the error messages mentioned earlier?

Comment: I have new errors messages. I proceed to 11. 50 all was fine until i did 11.51 adding another user and I've got 49 errors(:  I post another question since I don't think that ti could post soo long errors here in the message area. ... Also I was asked (maybe you can answer) how to keep my master branch clean? Ok, I got error on branch but those error went to master and even to another branch...I used git stash on branch but this dint' work this time? Any idea? I put question on ruby on rails listing 11.51 thanks

Comment: disregard the previous. But  I followed your instructions and created/renewed gmail, make "less secure"  and I've sent using local and it said that all send but I've never got  it by checking gmail. Any idea how to proceed?

Comment: you wrote "Please except my answer as the solution"  Please, let me know how to do so. I mean, where should I click/do something else to except your answer as solution? thanks.

Comment: @Tatyana Just click next to my answer that helped you solve your first problem. As far as the Heroku errors are concerned: You should create a new question and include Heroku as one of the tags. You will probably be able to find better help that way. I am sorry, I don't think I can help you with the Heroku errors.